# Finding how many elements of order $p$ are in the product of $\Bbb Z_{p^2} \times \Bbb Z_{p^2}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification

> How many elements are of order $p$ in $Z_{p^2}\times Z_{p^2}?$ Here, I believe $p$ is prime.

My attempt was to write out how many ways we can write out $Z_{p^2}\times Z_{p^2} = Z_{p^4}$. I.e, how many ways to sum up to $4$ containing an order $p$ group. So we can have $1 + 1 + 1 +1$, $1 + 1 +2$, and $3 + 1$. Since these are prime order, then they are cyclic. Thus we have atleast one generating element $g \in Z_P$. Therefore there should be at least $7$ elements that are of order $p$. However, I am not sure how to show if this is actually equal to $7$. Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: It is not true that $\Bbb Z_{p^2}\times \Bbb Z_{p^2} = \Bbb Z_{p^4}$. It's not even true that $\Bbb Z_{p^2}\times \Bbb Z_{p^2} \cong \Bbb Z_{p^4}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Every cyclic group of order $n$ has exactly one subgroup (which is also cyclic then) of order $d$ for every divisor $d \mid n$. If we take a look at the situation for $n = p^2$, we will therefore get $p-1$ elements of order $p$, namely all generators (i.e. non-identity elements) of the subgroup of order $p$. Thus we know how many elements of order $p$ are in the factors. Can you continue?

Comment: How do we know that there are $p-1$ elements of order p? I think I get where each element, besides the identity, will have to generate the group of order $p$ since it is prime cyclic and there are no other subgroups. However, how do we infer how many elements are in this group from this fact?

Comment: Every element of order $p$ will generate a subgroup of order $p$, but there is only one such subgroup. Thus all the elements of order $p$ are contained in that subgroup. That means the elements or order $p$ are exactly given by the non-identity elements of that group of order $p$.

Comment: Just to make sure that this is clear: My argument shows that each of the factors has $p -1$ elements of order $p$. Now you need to look at the non-trivial tuples as well. But that is not that hard.